# How to get news based on models id?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have profile pages for every model from my site, but I need to get on every profile the news with `model_id` based on id of my model.

I have 3 tables :

1. **models** - `Id`,`Title`,`Phone`,`Number`,
2. **news** - `Id`, `Title`, 'Slug',
3. **news_models** - `Id`, `News_id`,`Models_id`.

**Here is my controller**

```
public function modelSingle($slug)
{

    // return $slug;
    // return Redirect::back();

    $data = $this->data;

    $data['model'] = Models::with('category_name','model_media')->where('slug','=',$slug)->first();
    $data['news'] = DB::table('news_models')->where('models_id', '=', 'news_id')->get(); // THIS IS WHAT I'VE TRIED TO DO
    dd($data['news']);
    $username = $data['model']->instagram;
    if($username)
    {
        $raw = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/'.$username);
        preg_match('/\"edge_followed_by\"\:\s?\{\"count\"\:\s?([0-9]+)/',$raw,$m);
        $data['followed_by'] = $m[1];
    }else{
        $data['followed_by'] = "";
    }

    // print intval($m[1]);
    // print_r($m);
    // die;
    if(count($data['model']) == 0)
    {
        abort(404);
    }

    $data['model_images'] = ModelMedia::where([["type", "=", 1],["model_id", "=", $data['model']->id]])->orderBy('sort')->get();

    $data['model_image'] = ModelMedia::where([["type", "=", 1],["tag", "=", 1],["model_id", "=", $data['model']->id]])->orderBy('sort')->get();
    $data['model_campaign'] = ModelMedia::where([["type", "=", 1],["tag", "=", 2],["model_id", "=", $data['model']->id]])->orderBy('sort')->get();
    $data['model_show'] = ModelMedia::where([["type", "=", 1],["tag", "=", 3],["model_id", "=", $data['model']->id]])->orderBy('sort')->get();

    $data['model_videos'] = ModelMedia::where([["type", "=", 2],["model_id", "=", $data['model']->id]])->get();
    $data['model_video'] = ModelMedia::where([["type", "=", 2],["tag", "=", 1],["model_id", "=", $data['model']->id]])->get();
    $data['video_campaign'] = ModelMedia::where([["type", "=", 2],["tag", "=", 2],["model_id", "=", $data['model']->id]])->orderBy('sort')->get();
    $data['video_show'] = ModelMedia::where([["type", "=", 2],["tag", "=", 3],["model_id", "=", $data['model']->id]])->get();

    $data['model_gif'] = ModelMedia::where([["type", "=", 3],["tag", "=", 1],["model_id", "=", $data['model']->id]])->get();
    // $data['model_gif'] = ModelMedia::where([["type", "=", 3],["model_id", "=", $data['model']->id]])->get();
    $data['gif_campaign'] = ModelMedia::where([["type", "=", 3],["tag", "=", 2],["model_id", "=", $data['model']->id]])->get();
    $data['gif_show'] = ModelMedia::where([["type", "=", 3],["tag", "=", 3],["model_id", "=", $data['model']->id]])->get();
```

With `dd($data['model']);` I get all data from table `models`, but I don't know how to add it in my `$data['news']` and allocate the correct news to model id.

So, If I'm on `/models/anna`, I want to get the news who are allocated to `models_id` ( from news_models ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have `Has Many Through` relation.

In **Model** Model:

```php
public function news()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough('App\News', 'App\Model');
}
```

In Controller:

```php
$model = Models::with('category_name','model_media')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
$news = $model->news;
```

Relationships documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Comment: correct approach, but it seems for me models_news better setup as pivot / many-to-many